# GurobiError: Unable to convert argument to an expression

Tags: python, gurobi

can someone help me with this error?
Where shoudl I look when I get the error: GurobiError: Unable to convert argument to an expression. 
I should add that i'm using Gurobi library in python

```
from gurobipy import*

m=Model('mymodel')

def label(c):
    return "x" + str(c).translate(None, " '")

shifts = [1,2]    
hours = [1,2]
games = ['bj', 'cr']
pits = [1,2]
order1 = [1,2]
order2 = [1,2,3]
combo, oi = multidict( {
 (1,1,'bj',1,1,1): 100,
 (1,1,'bj',1,1,2):200,
 (1,1,'bj',1,1,3):200,
 (1,1,'bj',1,2,1):50,
 (1,1,'bj',1,2,2):70,
 (1,1,'bj',1,2,3):70,
 (1,1,'cr',1,1,1):400,
 (1,1,'cr',1,1,2):450
})

combo= tuplelist(combo)
for s  in shifts:
    for t in hours:
        for i in games:
            for n in order1:
                     m.addConstr(quicksum(x[s,t,i,p,n,k] for s,t,i,p,n,k in combo.select(s,t,i,'*',n,'*'))- int(1)== 0, name=label((s,t,i,p,n,k))
```

Answer (score 0):

Gurobi will complain if you try to add a constraint with no model variables.  It looks like for some combination of variables the list enumeration will construct the empty list, ie:

`m.addConstr(quicksum([]) - 1 == 0)`

aka

`m.addConstr(-1 == 0)`

which is not possible.  In fact gurobi will still throw an error in the following example as even though it is feasible the expression contains no variables.

`m.addConstr(-1 <= 0)`

To solve this just check the list is non-empty before adding the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in Gurobi 6.0.0. There `quicksum([])` returns a linear expression with value 0 (instead of a float 0.0) and this solves the original problem.

The problem in version 5.6.3 and before is the use of the so called [TempConstr](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/5.6/reference-manual/py_tempconstr#pythonclass:TempConstr).

When you call [addConstr](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/5.6/reference-manual/py_model_addconstr), you can use the explicit "lefthandside", "operator", "righthandside" approach:

```
m.addConstr(quicksum([]), GRB.EQUAL, 0)
```

This will work without problems.

If you use [TempConstr](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/5.6/reference-manual/py_tempconstr#pythonclass:TempConstr) and use `quicksum` on an empty list, what really goes on is the following:

```
m.addConstr(quicksum([]) == 0)
```

`quicksum` returns 0, if the list is empty, so your statement is:

```
m.addConstr(0 == 0)
```

and `0 == 0` is converted to `True`, so you actually call:

```
m.addConstr(True)
```

and this is obviously something Gurobi cannot handle (but it could give a better error description).

To sum things up: If you use quicksum and there is a chance, that a list is empty, you can either check if the list is empty as suggested by blueenvelope, use the explicit approach or use a small wrapper method, if this happens quite often:

```
def add_constr(model, expression, name=""):
    if expression is True:
        return model.addConstr(0, GRB.EQUAL, 0, name)
    elif expression is False:
        raise Exception('`False` as constraint for {}'.format(name))
    else:
        return model.addConstr(expression, name)
```

This wrapper works for TempConstr as expression only.